# Win8.1: how to Get fingerprint sensor EgisTec ES603 to work?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, fingerprint, biometrics

**My Status**: I have a Win8.1 system (no Upgrade 1). I have purchased the EgisTec ES603 fingerprint sensor in Amazon. It comes with an installation disk. I have installed the driver and the device is now showing up in the device manager (Geräte Manager in German) without any yellow triangle. So it should work fine.

**My Problem**: How can I get the Win8.1 fingerprint app running? According to several support articles, one can go to the account page and get the fingerprint option page. This should be a standard Win8.1 feature. But the account apge is only showing the normal login options. ALso when going to the Start Screen and typing fingerprint, the option to go to the Accountinformation is presented (Anmeldeinformation in German). This leads to the same page with login options. But no fingerprint enrollment is possible.

**My Questions:**

1. Is the ES603 compatible with the Win8.1 Biometric Framework?
2. What needs to be done to get the ES603 working in Win8.1?
3. Any links to additional download sites?

Thanks a lot

/* Removing some embarassing typos... */

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [floc](https://superuser.com/users/429165/floc) Egistec doesn't send the driver to customers beacuse of legal issue with its OEM partners.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx5DvDGJR1wYOFBWUFcwWTB6RmM/view?usp=sharing) is the 64-bit driver that supports Windows 10, Windows 8.1, and Windows 7 and supports the [Windows Biometric Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In case of dead or expired link: go to the [Acer Support](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers) website, look for TravelMate P446-M, and download the current version of the `Elantech Touchpad` drivers

Download.Category....Vendor...........Description.........Version.....Size.......Date 
[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx5DvDGJR1wYOFBWUFcwWTB6RmM/view?usp=sharing).TouchPad...ELANTECH..Touchpad Driver 3.4.29.0 36.3 MB 2015/01/16

Comment: Why are we linking to a google drive instead of Acer support?

Comment: The following driver from Acer Support for P446-M worked for me on Windows 8.1: Fingerprint STMicro Fingerprint Driver 3.5.1.0 47.6 MB 2016/01/08

Comment: Thanks, the driver worked perfectly for my Clevo laptop equipped with an ES603 sensor. (under Windows 10 x64). After installing it and registering my fingerprints, Windows Hello now appears in Windows 10 Sign In Options.

Comment: Please don't report the driver worked or didn't work.  Just upvoted or downvote the answer.  That is more then enough to indicate if the answer was helpful or not.

Comment: @JakubBerezanski it worked for my bioexcess fingerprint as well

Comment: Please don't leave comments saying it worked.  Just issue a vote, every comment, pings me.  What I knew was going to happen, happened, the google drive link is dead.   Please don't replace links to anything but Acer people.

Comment: @AMB That's what the author wanted.  They wanted Elan Touchpad drivers that supported 8.1 so that's what I supplied

Comment: I am the person who asked the original question. Never got it running until I found this answer. I tried it and one reboot later it was working. Win10, 64 Bit, using Windows Hello. Thanks a lot for  helping. You brightened my day. I am really, really happy. Fixed the fingerprint reader to my monitor and now it is super-easy to log in.

Comment: @Splash Yet, you accepted a different answer, instead of this one.

Comment: @ramhound Thanks for the feedback, being new to the web superuser, I was not aware. Hope I now accepted this comment. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the Services (run services.msc) and enable the Windows Biometric Framework.

Comment: Was not running on mine, but starting it didn't seem to help for my Sager with EgisTec ES603 running Windows 8.1 Pro. Still can't find any of the fingerprint options under account or start menu.

Answer (score 1):

1. It does not appear so at present.
2. The main item is the device driver. This allows it to work with certain software. I have version 3.0.15.0 if that is of any help.
3. http://www.egistec.com/en/products/bioexcess.aspx

As the EgisTec doesn't currently support WBF, your only options are BioExcess, and manufactures re-branding of similar software. BioExcess does work with Win 8.1 successfully. However the lack of WBF means that the third party software is the only option.

Comment: Hi leoleo, thanks for the answer, I think this covers it. I tried BioExcess and could not get it working with Win8.1 (but I had a lot of upgrade trouble with Win8.1 at that time, which might have interferred. So it might work...)

Answer (score 1):

Friends, I have an EgisTec ES603 scanner and I managed to get it working through an awkward cocktail of drivers and prayer. I'm happy to share my drivers and instructions.

1. Download the ES603 driver [here](https://mega.nz/#!8wphxDaC!5z3mTKBY0OMyXSe9sSxGcdz-o-zmU5jFRxIvH4zr2n4). Excuse my rather arrogant language in the readme, even if I am correct.
2. Extract the contents of the "INF files.zip" file. Right-click the .inf file and select 'install'. This allows Windows to recognise the USB device far enough to permit further driver installations for it.
3. Run "2 - Driver Setup.exe". It's a standard EgisTec driver installer, but will fail without the first step having been satisfied. This explains to Windows fully what the device is.
4. Run the Setup in the third zip to link the Driver to Windows' Biometric Framework (WBF). You need this to be able to sign in properly.
5. Reboot your machine.
6. Sign in as normal and go to your user settings section. In Windows 8 this is through the 'settings' option in the Charms; in Windows 10 it's in the "All Settings" section of the Action Centre.
7. Set up a PIN for your account. I haven't checked in Windows 8, but in Windows 10 you need this to activate "Windows Hello", which permits use of fingerprints to sign in.
8. Enrol your finger prints!

Hope this helps you all.